# How to pass a parameterized class as an argument

Tags: java, generics

My goal is to develop a class that can output an object of a specified class.

```
public class GetMe<T> {
    public T get() {
        Object obj = generateObject();
        return (T) obj;
    }
}
```

Now, I know this isn't possible due to erasure.  So, we can pass in a class instance and use that to cast.

```
public class GetMe<T> {
    public GetMe<T>(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T get() {
        Object obj = generateObject();
        return clazz.cast(obj);
    }
}
```

This works great!  As long as the class isn't parameterized.  If it is, then I've got a problem.

I'm not allowed to use `List<String>.class`.  If I pass in a ParameterizedType (which in itself is difficult to generate), there's no `cast` method to use.

Is there a way out of this quagmire?

Comment: There is a way to retain generics at run time, but what is `generateObject` and why can't it return an object of type `T`?

Comment: look at this examples, might help: http://serdom.eu/ser/2007/03/25/java-generics-instantiating-objects-of-type-parameter-without-using-class-literal

Comment: Let's say `generateObject()` is a third-party deserializer.  I know it's of type T, because I serialized it earlier, but the method nonetheless only returns Object.  It could also be the result of a method.invoke, which only returns Object.

Comment: Yochai: Funny, I tried doing exactly what one of examples recommended ( `(Class<T>) paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];` ).  Unfortunately, this will often fail as there's absolutely no guarantee that a `Type` is a `Class`.  For example, `List` is a `Type` that castable to `Class`, but `List<String>` is a Type that isn't castable to `Class`.

Comment: Buy you can't create an instance of List<String> anyway... you need to return an actual Class. (new ArrayList<String>() ) .... List<> is an interface. You can use a constraint to guarantee it's an object: public class GetMe<T extends Object>

Answer (score 5):

I think [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) may solve this problem for you.

Comment: +1 because super type tokens are super-flexible. Should have mentioned them in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `List<String>` is that, because of erasure, it would at runtime indistinguishable from any other `List<?>`. The easiest way around this is to create a new class or interface which has the generic part "fixed", like

```
public interface StringList extends List<String> {
    /* nothing to see here */
}
```

This way you have a type token (the `StringList.class` object) which you can pass around at runtime and specifies exactly what you want, but without the need for generics at runtime.

Comment: I like this idea, but wouldn't I then need many of these "fixed" classes"?  Is there a way to make them at run-time?  I used List<String> in my example; in my project it is actually `Map<Domain, Map<String, Number>>`, where Domain could be one of ~200 object, some of which are themselves parameterized.

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a small idea. I'm not really sure if it will fit in your context but nevertheless:

```
public class GetMe<T>
{
    public List<T> getList() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> result = (List<T>) new LinkedList(); 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is where I'm leaning, just so I can move on with my life (even though it is "less correct").

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is how you plan to instantiate a `List` object. If you disclose more of what you are trying to build, we may be able to help you better.

You may want to use Type instead of Class. Type can represent all generic types, although it's not pleasant to work with.

```
abstract public class GetMe<T> 
{
    Type type;
    public GetMe<T>(Type type) 
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Another problem is how to create a generic type like `List<String>`. The "super type token" looks neat in syntax, in reality it's basically

```
static class XX extends TypeReference<List<String>>{}
....
Type typeListString = Util.extract(XX.class);
```

I would much prefer this way

```
List<String> f;

Type typeListString = getDeclaredField("f").getGenericType();
```

Actually, many of these frameworks that do fancy runtime generic magics are working on instance fields only.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that you're trying to create an object from `List<>` which in face it an interface, not an object.
So no matter what you'd try, you just can't create an instance of `List<>` , (interfaces aren't actual classes, and don't have constructors)

Try using a constraint to avoid having interfaces put in the declaration:

```
public class GetMe<T extends Object>
```

This will guarantee that **T**  is an actual class and not an interface.