# Working with Class<V> and generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics

Say I have the following Java method

```
static <V> KK<V> foo(Class<? extends V> c) {
    return null;
}
```

where KK is the following generic class:

```
class KK<T> {   
}
```

The following then compiles:

```
KK<String> x = foo(String.class);
```

But this doesn't:

```
KK<Collection<String>> x = foo(Collection.class);
```

due to "incompatible types: required: `KK<Collection<String>>` found: `KK<Collection>`

If I define foo as follows:

```
static <V> KK<V> foo(Class<? super V> c) {
    return null;
}
```

the previous call compiles, but so does the following,

```
KK<Collection<String>> x = foo(Object.class);
```

which I'd wish would not.

The reason is that `Class<V>` can only take a raw type. My question is, is there a way to work around this, namely I want foo to take `Class<C>` where `C` is the raw type of `V`. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a parameterized class as an argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980011/how-to-pass-a-parameterized-class-as-an-argument) and [Java: how do I get a class literal from a generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type)

Comment: Agreed -- pleas see the answer linked by @PaulBellora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.co.il/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)
- [An implementation of type tokens in Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html)

Comment: It would be appreciated if you added some code on how those "Super Type Tokens" solved your problem :)